# PrestaShop 1.7 HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to install PrestaShop 1.7 on my VPS and I am seeing a HTTP ERROR 500 when I navigate to my domain?

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Which are the configuration of your VPS?

Comment: Enable dev mode to see what error you get, edit _/config/defines.inc.php_ and change `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true`.

Comment: - open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)

- change false-->true:

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

Comment: Enable errors at `Advanced parameters -> Performance -> Debug mode`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to extract the file prestashop.zip and then fix all directory and file permission. If you have access to a command line, please exec the following command:

**From the directory installation execute:**

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

**and after finished:**

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After this, **go to the web installation type in the browser:**

```
http://yourdomain/directory_of_prestashop
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the PHP Version from 7.2 down to 7.0 resolved the issue for me.

As of Prestashop 1.7.3 PHP 7.2 is not supported. Support will only arrive with 1.7.4

Comment: For Prestashop 1.7.6.5 PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1):

For PrestaShop 1.7.0.5 I had Error 500.
What I did to resolve the error to be able to install is:

1. Unpack ZIP, delete index.php and Install_PrestaShop.html.
2. Unzip prestashop.zip
3. chmod 644 on these files: install/index.php,
   admin/index.php, admin/ajax.php, admin/ajax-tab.php, index.php.

I have also switched PHP from default 5.4 to 5.5. Then the installer came up. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version, if your server has not ssl, you could need to set $ssl to false in:
     /prestashop/controllers/front/AuthController.php

Or you can create an override in:
    /prestashop/override/controllers/front/AuthController.php

to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem... HTTP 500 error... Nothing has worked for me. But I have found solution. Problem is on hosting server PHP version. Here is a table where are official PHP requirements, but it's really not correct for a new installation of prestashop, not sure for update of PS.

[image: official requirements table]

I have tried many solutions (language change, permission change, but nothing has worked for me). So as a last thing I have tried was PHP ver. change from 5.6 to 7.2 and then everything was installed correctly with no errors in Slovak langauge (Prestashop v 1.7.5.1). I have tested PHP versions 7.0 and 7.1, but there was an errors too.

So the solution for me was to change hosting server PHP to ver. 7.2 and everything is fine now for me now.

[image: PS 1.7.5.1 - after installation]

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the .htaccess file helped me.
    You need to login in to your admin panel.
    Go to Shop Parameters -> Traffic & SEO.
    Set 'Friendly URL' No and Click on Save button.
    Now, Set 'Friendly URL' yes back and Click on Save Button.
    Now “. htaccess” regenerated Successfully on your server.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is related to your site's localization settings. You can try following steps:

1. Open file, *yourdomain.com/config/**config.inc.php***
2. Found code, `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale.'.UTF-8', $locale.'.utf8');`
3. And convert to comment line, `//setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale.'.UTF-8', $locale.'.utf8');`